# How to add library path in bnd file in liferay7?

Tags: liferay-7

[image]I have created a module project using mvc-portlet.For my project, I need to import a few jar files.
For this purpose, I have created a lib file in the project module and have added its path to the build.gradle .Now while building the project is working, but at the time of deployment it is not starting(i.e.: the portlet stays in installed phase).
I understand it is because I have not added the lib folder path in my and files. But I am not sure as to how should I proceed regarding it. 
I am using eclipse ide and Liferay 7 along with tomcat for development

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to know why your module is not working, I suggest you tu use the diag command on the Gogo Shell.

Now, to manage the problem with the libraries, you have to include the jar files (extracted) inside your module, this is create a fat jar. Basically add a task to your build gradle like this:

```
task customFatJar(type: Jar) {
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

It could be great if you create a fat jar with only the libraries, and export it's packages on the bnd, and then you consume them from a different module.